# R: quick question about [CPS85$wage < 40,]

Tags: r

While following a tutorial I found in a github, there was a code like this:

`plotdata <- CPS85[CPS85$wage < 40,]`

And I don't really understand why would I need that comma(,) right before the bracket.

.

So I tried running without the comma,

`plotdata <- CPS85[CPS85$wage < 40]`

I got this error message: **Error in [.data.frame`(CPS85, CPS85$wage < 40) :
undefined columns selected**

.

Can anybody explain why I should include comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma is for selecting rows with condition `wage < 40`. The syntax is globally `data.frame[rows, columns]`. The blank after the comma means you select all the columns.

Comment: You're welcome! Welcome on SO! Don't forget to validate an answer once you get your answer @JayHyojinLee